# How to prevent progress bar animation from writing to multiple lines?

Tags: python, progress-bar, pysimplegui

I have this code:

```py
animation = ["[■□□□□□□□□□]", "[■■□□□□□□□□]", "[■■■□□□□□□□]", "[■■■■□□□□□□]",
             "[■■■■■□□□□□]", "[■■■■■■□□□□]", "[■■■■■■■□□□]", "[■■■■■■■■□□]",
             "[■■■■■■■■■□]", "[■■■■■■■■■■]"]

import sys

for i in range(len(animation)):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + animation[i % len(animation)]+ "\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

But the animation is one by one like this:

```
[■□□□□□□□□□]

[■■□□□□□□□□]
```

Instead of replacing the boxes. How can I make it look like an animation?

Edit: i forget to mention that i use it inside a pysimpleguy layout. Dont know if it its important.

Comment: Couple questions: why are you using `sys.stdout` over `print()`? Why not simply iterate over the animation strings directly instead of using an index and modulus? I.e.: `for anim in animations:`

Comment: What does `t.generate()` do? You need to provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: @martineau the t.generate() makes an torrent file, it is what i want to make a progress bar for.

Comment: Since that has nothing to do with your question, it should have been removed in order to have the absolute _minimum_ amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @martineau Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rich library](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich) to make progress bars.

Here is some example code.

```
import time

from rich.progress import Progress

with Progress() as progress:

    task = progress.add_task("[green]Processing...", total=1000)

    while not progress.finished:
        progress.update(task, advance=0.5)
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `"\n"` you move the cursor to a new line and hence the next `"\r"` simply returns to the beginning of *that line*. Just remove the `"\n"` and it will work.

Comment: i added the "\n" to look more beautiful. because it first show side by side instead of line by line

Comment: @Cristina Well that's what the `"\r"` is used for, return the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Removing the \n will not work: https://i.imgur.com/204THIX.png, i forget to mention that i use it inside a pysimpleguy layout. Dont know if it its important.

Comment: @Cristina: Do you mean "PySimpleGUI"? If so, then ***yes*** it matters a great deal. PySimpleGUI has somethings called `ProgressBar` and `one_line_progress_meter` — look them up.